# QR Scanner is display black screen on restart

Tags: flutter, dart, qr-code

I am developing a qr scanner app. I have an issue that when I restart the app on mobile it displays black screen but when I perform a reload it works fine. This bug only occurs in mobiles. It works fine in the emulator.

Answer (score 0):

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  if (controller != null && mounted) {
    controller!.pauseCamera();
    controller!.resumeCamera();
  }

  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you was used [qr_code_scanner](https://pub.dev/packages/qr_code_scanner) plugIN
and right now in this plugIn there is no more up to dated and maintenance mode only.

Note [(from plug IN)](https://pub.dev/packages/qr_code_scanner)
Since the underlying frameworks of this package, zxing for android and MTBBarcodescanner for iOS are both not longer maintaned, this plugin is no longer up to date and in maintenance mode only. Only bug fixes and minor enhancements will be considered.

and alternative of this plugIn is [mobile_scanner 2.1.0](https://pub.dev/packages/mobile_scanner)

but are you still want to used qr_code_scanner plugIn then follow this way

override this method

// In order to get hot reload to work we need to pause the camera if the platform
// is android, or resume the camera if the platform is iOS.

```
  QRViewController? controller;

 @override
  void reassemble() async {
    super.reassemble();

    if (controller != null) {
      debugPrint('reassemble : $controller');
      if (Platform.isAndroid) {
        await controller!.pauseCamera();
      } else if (Platform.isIOS) {
        await controller!.resumeCamera();
      }
    }
  }
```

in side build method for auto hot reload do this

Note : this is for Android ( i don't try on IOS may be worked )

```
 if (controller != null && mounted) {
      setState(() {
        controller!.resumeCamera();
      });
    }
```

see my full code

this page was navigated from another page and scanner will open here.

```
class ScanQrCode extends StatefulWidget {
  static const routeName = 'scanQrCode';
  const ScanQrCode({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ScanQrCode> createState() => _ScanQrCodeState();
}

class _ScanQrCodeState extends State<ScanQrCode> {
  final GlobalKey qrKey = GlobalKey(debugLabel: 'QR');
  Barcode? result;
  QRViewController? controller;

  // In order to get hot reload to work we need to pause the camera if the platform
  // is android, or resume the camera if the platform is iOS.
  @override
  void reassemble() async {
    super.reassemble();

    if (controller != null) {
      debugPrint('reassemble : $controller');
      if (Platform.isAndroid) {
        await controller!.pauseCamera();
      } else if (Platform.isIOS) {
        await controller!.resumeCamera();
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller?.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
// for auto hot reload 
    if (controller != null && mounted) {
      setState(() {
        controller!.resumeCamera();
      });
    }
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        elevation: 0.0,
        systemOverlayStyle: const SystemUiOverlayStyle(
          statusBarColor: Colors.transparent,
        ),
        centerTitle: true,
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
        title: Text(
          'Scan Any QR',
          style: UPITextStyle.boldOblique.copyWith(
            fontSize: 18,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
          ),
        ),
        actions: [
          Container(
            width: 24,
            height: 24,
            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 15),
            child: FloatingActionButton(
              elevation: 0.0,
              materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,
              splashColor: Colors.transparent,
              focusColor: Colors.transparent,
              hoverColor: Colors.transparent,
              autofocus: false,
              disabledElevation: 0,
              focusElevation: 0,
              highlightElevation: 3,
              hoverElevation: 0,
              backgroundColor: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.5),
              onPressed: () => Navigator.maybePop(context),
              child: Icon(
                Icons.close,
                size: 14,
                color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.7),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Flexible(
            flex: 5,
            child: buildQrView(context),
          ),
          Flexible(
            flex: 2,
            child: SizedBox(
              child: Text('${controller?.getCameraInfo()}'),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget buildQrView(BuildContext context) {
    // if (controller != null && mounted) {
    //   setState(() {
    //     controller!.resumeCamera();
    //   });
    // }
    return QRView(
      key: qrKey,
      onQRViewCreated: onQRViewCreated,
      overlay: QrScannerOverlayShape(
        borderColor: upiMidNightBlue,
        borderWidth: 8,
        borderLength: 25,
        borderRadius: 15,
        overlayColor: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5),
      ),
    );
  }

  void onQRViewCreated(QRViewController control) {
    setState(
      () {
        controller = control;
        debugPrint('controller : $controller');
      },
    );
  }
}
```

hope this will help you